# Azure AD App Registration certificate credentials - What should the certificate common name be?

Tags: azure-active-directory, ssl-certificate

When using a [certificate for authentication to Microsoft Identity Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#add-a-certificate), are there specific details required for the certificate? Does Azure AD actually verify if the common name matches the server?

If my app registration is for a web app, could I just re-use the same SSL certificate that's used for the HTTPS binding?

For a daemon app, I guess the common name should be the hostname FQDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Azure AD does not verify a match between the certificate CN and the host name. Also:

1. A 2048-bit size is highly recommended for the best combination of
   security and performance.
2. It must use the RSA cryptographic algorithm.
3. Can be signed with SHA256, SHA384 and SHA512 hash
   algorithms.